# PHP MySQL, Find Tables with variations of a name

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have one or more tables in my MySQL DB. Named: 'SCI-01-123' AND 'SCI-01-123-1', etc.

I want to search for all table names with the base name: 'SCI-01-123' and the added -1, -2 etc.
My $result->num_rows shows 2 rows, but I do not get two names when I implode the array. Only the first.

What am I doing wrong?
Is my query wrong or should I handle the array differently. I have looked at the PHP and MySQL documentation, but I can not find a solution.

```
$patient_id = 'SCI-01-123'; //looking for 'SCI-01-123' AND 'SCI-01-123-1'

$query = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$patient_id%'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
    echo "num_rows: $result->num_rows\n";
    $array =  $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo implode("\n", $array) . "\n";

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo "$value\n";
    }
    // both echo only the first table name: SCI-01-123
    
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
    echo  "query error";
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: fetch_assoc only fetchs one record. In your case you may use fetch_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$result->fetch_assoc()` - Fetch the next row of a result set as an
> associative array

To fetch all result rows as an associative array or a numeric you should instead use

```
$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) or $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM)
```

Try this

```
$patient_id = 'SCI-01-123'; //looking for 'SCI-01-123' AND 'SCI-01-123-1'

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$patient_id%'")) {
    echo "num_rows: $result->num_rows\n";
    $array = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM); // returns a numeric array or arrays

    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        echo $arr[0].PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}else{
    echo  "query error";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm.